# Function that trims whitespace and ads punctuation if there is none

Tags: php

I am trying to make a function that cuts the white spaces in a string and ads punctuation if there isn't any.

This is my test string:

```
$test = 'Hey there I am traa la la           ';
```

I want it to turn into this:

```
$test = 'Hey there I am traa la la.';
```

Here is the function I have tried:

```
function test($mytrim){
        for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){
            if(substr($mytrim, 0, -1) == ''){
                $mytrim = substr($mytrim, 0, -1);
            }
        }
        $punct = array(".",",","?","!");
        if(!in_array($mytrim, $punct)){ $mytrim .= '.'; } 
        return $mytrim;
    }
```

It returns this:

```
$mytrim = 'Hey there I am traa la la. .';
```

Any ideas why it is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP has a built in [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function. as for the punctuations, your code should work fine (appending).

Code sample :

```
<?php

    $testString = "   hello world      ";
    $trimmedString = trim($testString); // will contain "hello world"
    $lastChar = substr($trimmedString, strlen($trimmedString)-1); // will be "d"
    $punct = array(".",",","?","!");
    if(!in_array($lastChar, $punct))
        echo $trimmedString.'.'; //will output "hello world."
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function test ($string)
{
    $string = trim($string);
    if ((substr($string, -1)) != ".")
    {
         $string .= ".";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function adspunctuation($str)
{
   $str = trim($str) . (substr($str, -1)!='.' ? '.' : '');
   return $str;
}
```

Comment: that wont work - it should only add a punctuation if there isnt already one there

Comment: Edit according to specification... similar to your code just using ternary operator.